# create table to a role and role to user in oracle

Tags: oracle

i am creating a role name developer

```
create role developer ;
grant create session,create table to developer
```

then again i am creating a user

```
create user dhoni identified by dhoni
```

granting the role to dhoni

```
grant role developer to dhoni ;
create table xx(sno number(11));
```

it not create the table

```
 the error 
ORA-01031: insufficient privileges
```

Comment: please share the actual code, and please format it. also, it's possible you've granted the role, but it's not enabled, use the DEFAULT ROLE syntax. And, if you're on a newer version of Oracle, you'll need to grant tablespace quota to DHONI so they can occupy space in their default tablespace.

Comment: try ALTER USER DHONI DEFAULT ROLE DEVELOPER;

Comment: ya i done it but it insufficient privilege

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grant role developer to dhoni ;
```

That's invalid - it should be

```
grant developer to dhoni;
```

Then your create table will work.

Comment: can you plz explain differences between create role developer; and create role developer identified by xxxx

Comment: on 'identified by' - the user must be authorized before the role is enabled

Comment: can you give a example please

Answer (score 0):

May be below solution will help.

```
SQL> show user
USER is "SYS"
SQL>

SQL> create role developer;

Role created.

SQL> grant create session,create table to developer;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> create user dhoni identified by dhoni;

User created.

SQL> grant developer to dhoni;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn dhoni/dhoni
Connected.

SQL> show user
USER is "DHONI"

SQL> CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);  2    3    4    5    6    7

Table created.

SQL>
```